# Modification of QuickSort (partition Hoare), first even numbers descending, then odd numbers descending

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have a big problem to modify the Hoare partition so that it sorts in descending order: first by even numbers and then by odd numbers. Example: arr[] = {1, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5},                      out: arr[] = {8, 6, 4, 7, 5, 1}.

I was able to do this by dividing the array separately into even and odd numbers and sorting each of these parts separately. However, the task is to rework the quicksort so that you do not have to divide the array.

Below I have my partition, I'm going in the right direction?

```
static int partition(int []arr, int low,  
                                int high) 
{ 
    int pivot = arr[low]; 
    int i = low - 1, j = high + 1; 

    while (true) 
    { 

        do
        { 
            i++; 
        } while ((arr[i] > pivot && ((arr[i]%2==0 && pivot%2==0) || (arr[i]%2!=0 && pivot%2!=0))) || (arr[i]<pivot && arr[i]%2==0 && pivot%2!=0)); 


        do
        { 
            j--; 
        } while (arr[j] < pivot); 

        if (i >= j) 
            return j; 
        int temp = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = arr[j]; 
        arr[j] = temp; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem and where did you run into problems?

Comment: I solved the problem only the wrong way. I created 2 additional tables: one with even numbers and the other with odd numbers. I sorted them separately and copied the result to the original array. However, the task is about modifying the quicksort, so my way is not compatible with the content of the task. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

Comment: share your code you have tried so far.

Comment: You just need to modify the comparison used by the sort. But it can't just be as simple as `a < b`  always means "`a` sorts after `b`" anymore;  parity (odd/even) matters, too.  Now `a < b` only means "`a` sorts after `b`" when `a` and `b` are both odd or both even;  but when one is odd and the other even, the even one always sorts after the odd one,

Comment: Ok, I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did an effort in the condition of the first loop, but:

- It is not entirely correct
- It should be applied similarly to the second loop condition as well

For the second reason it may be good to define a compare-function:

```
    private static int cmp(int a, int b) {
        if (a % 2 != b % 2) return a % 2 - b % 2; 
        return b - a;
    }
```

Now the loop conditions should be simple:

- `while (cmp(arr[i], pivot) < 0)`
- `while (cmp(arr[j], pivot) > 0)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's almost good, but I replaced these while loops with the ones you wrote. However, now for example: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} prints {5, 3, 1, 2, 4} and should be: {5, 3, 1, 4, 2}.

Comment: I suppose that means your surrounding code is not good? See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/QuickSortCmp)

Comment: Unfortunately, the one you sent is also incorrect. Output should be: 4 2 5 3 1, not 4 2 1 3 5.

Comment: Somehow I understood that the odd ones should be in ascending order. So let me fix that then. Hold on...

Comment: I have corrected that now. Just remove one line from the `cmp` function.